# Fabric Correct initialization as my app won't be shown in fabric io dashboard

Tags: crashlytics-android

I managed to use both Answer and Crashlytic together. i did it before just with CrashLytic. 
But for my new app i can't initialize that again.
I see logs which shows everything is alright.
but my app is not in dashboard.
I used this code as one of the Twitter Staff mentioned [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/stuck-on-build-your-project-after-upgrading-crashlytics-to-fabric/31428/95):

```
Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this).debuggable(true).kits(new Crashlytics()).build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

In my log i see these lines :

```
D/Fabric: Requesting settings from ....
D/Fabric: Loaded settings: .....
D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file created.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Finalizing previously open sessions.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Closing open sessions.
D/CrashlyticsCore: Closed all previously open sessions
D/CrashlyticsCore: Initialization marker file removed: true
D/CrashlyticsCore: Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
D/CrashlyticsCore: Checking for crash reports...
D/CrashlyticsCore: No reports found.
```

But still my app won't be shown in dashboard. Any idea how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from Fabric side. Their support team solve the problem at their side. The initialization Code above is correct.